# How to remove some value array in codeigniter session

Tags: codeigniter, session

these my function
//store array data to session

```
function justSession($code)
{
    $data = $this->session->userdata('code');
    $data[] = $code;
    $this->session->set_userdata('code',$data);
}
```

then these function to print_r session

```
function printSession()
{
    print_r($this->session->userdata('code'));
}
```

and then output from printSession() is `Array([0]=>KG001[1]=>KG002[2]=>KG003)`

now, how to remove session 'code' with specified value? i'll to remove the KG001 in session?

Comment: what you need is `unset` or reassigning a null value to code `$this->session->userdata('code','')`

Comment: that way is removing 'code' session, i want to remove KG001 in 'code' session, and if KG001 removed printSession() will display Array([0]=>KG002[2]=>KG003)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->session->userdata($code) == 'KG001')
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata($code);
}
```

Am I understanding your question right?